# YugabyteDB backing up only 1 copy in replicated cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I noticed when i do backup /restore for single node i have no issue at all but for a multi-node cluster i would have issues with the backup. I see on the documentation regarding the tip below:

> To get a snapshot of a multi-node cluster, you need to go into each
> node and copy the folders of ONLY the leader tablets on that node.
> Because each tablet-replica has a copy of the same data, you do not
> need to keep a copy for each replica.

Not sure what this means , how would i get ONLY the leader tablets on that node?

Lets say we have a 3-node cluster, i would just backup all the leader tablet data of the current node , then do the same for the next 2 . At the end, i would restore it by copying only the leader tablet data on its own respective node, then restoring it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not sure what this means , how would i get ONLY the leader tablets on that node?

Based on the replication factor by default, or set for a tablespace explicitly, a tablet is replicated 3 times. You don't have to backup all copies. Just the tablet-leader data.
When you restore, you restore the tablet-leader data 3 times to 3 different servers (assuming RF 3).

> At the end i would restore by copying only the leader tablet data on its own respective node , then restoring it like that?

No. On restore, you'll need to copy to 3 replicas.